# Searching with ModelChoiceField in django

Tags: django, forms, search

### Suppose I have a form field as below:

```
admin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
    help_text=_('select an admin for this organization'),
    label=_('Organization Admin'),
)
```

when this form is rendered in a template and I can see a drop-down button on that field and can select an item.

But the number of items is so much that it is very difficult for me to select one.

I want a search option just on top of the drop-down list.

Is it possible? If possible, how?

Answer (score 3):

Part from my code:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class WorkForm(forms.Form):
    materials = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=_('Materials'), queryset=Goods.objects.filter(deleted=False), required=False, widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(_('materials'), True))

    class Media:
        css = {
                'all': (
                          '/static/admin/css/widgets.css',
                          '/static/css/widgets.css',
                       )
              }
        js = [
                '/admin/jsi18n/'
             ]
```

Or you can use https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2

Comment: The widget cannot be loaded with new forms added via JS. Could you help show me how?   `$('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));`

Comment: Where can i get `widgets.css` and relevant `js` defined on class `Media`

Answer (score 1):

This django plugin is quite helpful: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-autocomplete/

It works with jQuery, so you have to ensure that jQuery is working. You have just follow the four installation steps and adapt your form model.

Hope this helps.